# How to add Header and Footer to a Markdown File?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have a more general use case where I need to add my ***company logo to the Header of each page when I convert the Markdown to PDf document***. 
It is important to note that it is not the most basic question where I just need to add an image but instead I need a header and footer similar to as we do in a word file.

I have tried to figure out the solution but I got to know that it is possible using Sweave and in R Markdown. The markdown I have is Github Markdown.

I used Typora to crete the markdown and there is no option provided by Typora to do the same. Luckily I found that I could add Header and Footer to a Markdown by adding an Extension **"Markdown-Pdf"** to VS-Code but still it is not possible to configure the header and footer.

The official document of markdown-pdf gives the setting of markdown-pdf.headerTemplate but giving this argument a style does not work.

Comment: I can recommend pandoc, see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf and https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the html code in the options of the extension.

Open settings, search for  `markdown-pdf.headerTemplate` and put in your header styling, including the image. The image must be base64 encoded.

Here an example of how I use those settings with a title and a image.

```
"markdown-pdf.headerTemplate": "<div style=\"font-size: 9px; margin-left: 1cm;\"> <span>Some specific header text</span></div> 
<div style=\"margin-left: auto; margin-right: 1cm; \"> 
<img style='display:block; width:55px;' id='base64image' 
src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4A...A/9k=\"/></div>"
```

Unfortunately only base64 encoded images are working. For larger images this means o lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue too. Solved it by writing a Python script. It takes an image, converts it to Base64, and auto-updates the markdown-pdf.headerTemplate in VS Code's settings.json. You can even throw in your own HTML template. Just run the script and your next Markdown PDF will have the header you want.

```
import argparse, base64, json, logging, os, platform from PIL import Image
```

Example usage:

```
python3 ImageBase64VscodeConfigurator.py --i input.png --o output.txt --c 85 --s 50 --html new_template.html --header
```